# Повторное включение определения в нескольких файлах

Tags: c++, const

Есть свой хэдэрфайл для проекта, в нем определен константный массив строк типа:

```
#ifndef MW_HPP
#define MW_HPP

const char *OPTIONS[elements_of_complexity] {"EASILY", "MEDIUM", "COMPLICATED", "EXPERT"};

#endif
```

Но, несмотря на `ifndef` при компиляции выдает ошибку, что `OPTIONS` имеет определения во всех файлах проекта, где включен мой хэдэрфайл. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: если действительно нужен глобальный массив, то **объяви** в хедере через extern, а **определи** в каком-нибудь *.cpp-файле... ЗЫ: в С++17 ЕМНИП для этого сто-то ещё новое придумали...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с того, что ошибка возникает не при компиляции, а при компоновке (линковке) программы из разных модулей (единиц трансляции). Т.е. отдельно разные модули (cpp + h) компилируются без проблем, а когда настаёт время объединить их в один бинарник возникает проблема повторного определения одной и той же сущности.

Для устранения возникшей проблемы можно использовать `extern` и перенос определения в cpp файл, как уже сказано в соседнем ответе. Но есть и другой, более лёгкий для исправления способ - добавить ещё один `const` (после звёздочки) и сделать массив константным (исходно это массив констант, но не константный массив):

```
const char * const OPTIONS[] {"EASILY", "MEDIUM", "COMPLICATED", "EXPERT"};
```

Исчезновение ошибки в этом случае будет обусловлено тем, что константы по умолчанию имеют внутреннее связывание (internal linkage) и в процессе линковки не видны между модулями.

Также проблему можно решить другими способами с помощью `inline`, и с помощью `static`:

```
inline const char * OPTIONS[] {"EASILY", "MEDIUM", "COMPLICATED", "EXPERT"};

static const char * OPTIONS[] {"EASILY", "MEDIUM", "COMPLICATED", "EXPERT"};
```

оставляя при этом массив неконстантным, но с другими побочными эффектами.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не *объявили* массив, а *определили* его.

В заголовочном файле следовало бы написать

```
extern const char *OPTIONS[elements_of_complexity];
```

а то, что вы написали - в *одном* из .cpp-файлов.